# neo4j two fulltext searches in one subquery

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find the highest scoring fulltext query from two nodes:

```
(node1)-[:ACTED_IN]-(node2)

Where node1 can be e.g., a search:
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('movie_search', 'Matrix')
YIELD score, node as node1 

And node2 is the analogous: 
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('actor search', 'Fish')
YIELD score as scoreC, node as nodeC
```

This may be a subsearch (i.e., subsetting the graph after the first search). I am assuming this may be a subquery, but still trying to understand how this can be done using subqueries.

Ideally the top relationship will return a pair between the relation of Movie and Actor according to the fulltext search

```
#Movie, Actor,
"The Matrix", "Laurence Fishburne"
"The Matrix Reloaded", "Laurence Fishburne"
"Matrix Revolutions", "Laurence Fishburne"
"Apocalypse Now", "Laurence Fishburne # this one would have a lower score, but probably also show up
...
```

Comment: pls give us an example resulting set. thanks.

Comment: Added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the results of the first search to boost the score of the second, based on which movie node the actor node acted in.

You haven't told us what you want to do with the scores mathematically, so for this example I'll just add them.

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('movie_search', 'Matrix')
YIELD score, node as movie
WITH collect([movie, score]) as movieScores

CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('actor search', 'Fish')
YIELD score, node as actor
MATCH (actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie:Movie)
WITH score, actor, movie, coalesce([pair IN movieScores WHERE pair[0] = movie | pair[1]][0], 0) as movieScore
RETURN movie.title as movie, actor.name as actor, score + movieScore as totalScore
ORDER BY totalScore DESC
```

What we're doing is collecting the movies and their scores into a list that we can cross reference later. After we get the actor node we find all movies they acted in, and for each row find the movie/score pair for that movie (using coalesce() to use a default of 0 if none was found), then we add the scores and sort them.

Comment: This definitely does the trick. I wonder if for a much larger database, is it possible to limit to e.g., the top 10 nodes?

Comment: Yes. Just do an ORDER BY score (or whatever you want to use for ordering) and LIMIT 10. If you want to apply that to the movies results, then do that in a WITH clause but before you collect(). If you want to do that for the end, then apply that to the result of the score summing, but wait until after the ordering and LIMIT is applied to access the node properties.